# ZPL on an old Zebra 170XI

Tags: zpl

I have an old Zebra 170Xi that I would like to use to print labels.  Note: it is an plain Xi, not Xi4, XiIII, XiIII plus, or even XiII, so it is old.

I know it "works" because at least printing test stuff from the menu does write labels as expected.  I have not been able to print anything programmatically.

I've tried the equivalent of a ZPL hello world to the COM port with some redirection on the command line, but nothing came out.

Can someone give a pointer to at least bootstrap sending commands to the printer?

Comment: The USB to parallel/serial cable proved unreliable.  The solution was to use us a real parallel port via a PCI add on card.  Then I used the following steps to get my printer to print out the labels:  

1. add a real parallel port to my PC
2. create a text file with the ZPL contnent
3. on the command like types "copy zpl.txt LPT2"

The printer printed the contexts of the zpl.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you'd like to post **your** "Hello World"

This one should work:

```
^XA
^LH30,30
^FO20,10^AD^FDHELLO WORLD^FS
^XZ
```

Make sure there are no clever drivers - run the port as Text/Generic.

And use a text-editor to create the file above; simply `copy` it to the printer-port.

Oooh - that may be the problem. If you're using `CMD` then `^` is an escape character, so

```
echo ^XA
```

needs to be

```
echo ^^XA
```

Yeah - tough old brutes the 170Xi - got my Zebra stripes on them back in '95...

Comment: Maybe the way I am trying to configure and use the printer is wrong.

What are the steps you take to do a sanity check to see if a PC can print to an old printer like this?

Comment: I'd use a conventional parallel port, generic driver and a simple ZPL script such as the above - created using a text-editor such as notepad or editplus, not a WP. Probably better to use an ancient PC as well - to cash in on the availability of conventional ports without OS interference.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.  I've been trying USB->com/lpt cables.  I ordered a straight up COM and parallel port PCI card.  I'll see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I then just saved the hello world script to a file
Then in cmd.exe I did 
> copy hello_world.txt LPT2

It worked.